Free and Open Source Parquet File Viewer for Ubuntu
As the title reads, I am looking for a simple parquet file viewer (with basic column descriptions, type and previewing some values) on Ubuntu desktop.
I deal with some adhoc files occasionally. Even if I want to see the basic schema, I have to load them via polars or spark in a programming interface. It would save a lot of time if I could just open them for a quick preview like an excel file.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of the project.
Squey is an open-source visualization software designed to interactively explore and understand large amounts of tabular data.
Since version 5.0 it natively supports the import of Apache Parquet files. You can even import several Parquet files in one go provided they have the exact same structure.

